# Broken line-breaking in section title

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I'm having trouble with the automatic line-breaking in a section title of my document, but only when I compile on my laptop.  This is my document

```
\documentclass{article}

\tracingparagraphs=1
\listfiles

\begin{document}

\section{In (b) the nature of k was left intentionally unspecified. While it's true... }

\end{document}
```

And I keep getting the following:

[image]

However, when I copied the code into Overleaf, it looks perfectly normal:
[image]

I've tried compiling from the command line, deleting all the logs and such and recompiling then, but nothing's worked from my laptop.  What could be causing this problem?

EDIT: I've removed all the packages that I was using and still got the same problem.  Here is the contents of the .log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.2.11)  11 FEB 2018 13:11
entering extended mode
**./blah.tex
(blah.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (blah.aux)
\openout1 = `blah.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
@firstpass
[]\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 In (b) the nature of k was left intentionally 
@ via @@0 b=22 p=0 d=1024
@@1: line 1.1 t=1024 -> @@0
unspecified 
@\par via @@1 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@2: line 2.2- t=1124 -> @@1

@firstpass
[]\OT1/cmr/bx/n/14.4 . While it's true... 
@\par via @@0 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@1: line 1.2- t=100 -> @@0

 [1

{C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (blah.aux)


 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 208 strings out of 493303
 2394 string characters out of 3138853
 53826 words of memory out of 3000000
 3845 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4245 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,19p,179b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Pr
ogram Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on blah.pdf (1 page, 21427 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

UPDATE: Re-typing out the document fixed the problem, I was just too tired to retype my whole (actual, much longer document) last night.  I still have no idea what was causing this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for adding a minimal example that illustrates the problem. Unfortunately the example works fine for me on my laptop (just as you say it does on Overleaf), so it's not clear what the problem is. Could you try (1) further removing packages that don't affect the problem, and (2) adding `\tracingparagraphs=1` and paste the output from the `.log` file here?

Comment: The log file shows that indeed the section title is being line-broken as two paragraphs (one from “In” to “unspecified”, and one from “.” to “true…”). Could you copy the exact `blah.tex` file from your laptop, byte-for-byte, and paste it here, just to be sure? (The one currently in the answer is before you removed the packages for instance, and the line numbers don't match.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I've edited my post to match the changes made -- i.e. removing all packages, updating, and recompiling. I'm not sure how to upload the file.

Comment: My guess (after seeing your update) is that either the input really contained a blank line between the “unspecified” and the “.”, or that it contained some weird character that TeX was treating as a paragraph end. Hard to say now without the actual file, unfortunately. (If you had the original file, you could run `hexdump`  or `xxd` or something on it and paste the output; it would explain what was going on.)

Comment: Well, thanks anyways!  I'll try that next time if this problem comes up :)

Comment: (I've voted to close the question, because the problem went away with retyping, and there's no way to figure out now what was wrong.)